# Angularjs - open a PDF in a new tab : customize url

Tags: angularjs

I want to display a pdf file in a new tab. 
I retrieve the pdf from my server (J2EE/Spring MVC).
When I am getting the response I do :

```
ReportingLot.FicheStock.get({idLot:vm.lot.id}, function (response) {
    var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var pdfFile = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);


    window.open(pdfFile, '_blank');

});
```

The pdf displays in the new tab, but the url is :

> blob:http://localhost:8080/9e8eb169-afff-4013-9a7a-04c2efdfb7e3

is there a way to custom this ur to make it more understable for the users?
Thanks.

**[UPDATE]**

```
Response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"ficheStock.pdf\"");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
```

Comment: What exactly is "understable"? Isn't your backend generating this URL? So make the backend generate your PDF callback on an other URL?

Comment: I did (cf my update) but  I don't get the file name on the client side, I only get an array buffer.

Comment: Oh wow i see, dont you fear memory leaks by using `window.URL.createObjectURL(file);`?

Comment: I am not at that level of investigation yet... :) It seems hard to display a pdf file coming from a server with angularjs

Comment: Ehm, no its not hard. Put your PDF file on your server and make a link to it `<a href="http://localhost:8080/9e8eb169-afff-4013-9a7a-04c2efdfb7e3" target="_blank">Open PDF</a>`. It does the same like you did. No need for streaming that kind of filetype.

Comment: I don't want to store the PDF on the server. The PDF needs to be read as a stream.

Comment: You currently do store it on the server. Exactly inside the RAM (working storage).

Comment: Join me in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135273/howtodo

Comment: I wish I could, but I am new here, and I am not authorized to chat yet...

Comment: Now you should be able to do it :)

Comment: Apparently not yet :) "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq."

Comment: Yea, it take some time till the reputation is synced between all stack platforms, hang on.